# Xpages - How to access the newly generated UniversalID and send it on submit in Xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

I want to be able to send the UNID of the newly created document to the user, so that the user can access the document. In the execution script;

```
var unid = param.documentId;
var vUnid = newDocId.getDocument().getUniversalID;
```

Both were picking up the parent UNID, which already existed in the browser.

[image]

This image will show you how the document looks like and will be grateful to know how to pass the newly generated UNID when document is submitted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your code into the `postSave` event of your data source. The UNID for a new document only gets set when saved for the first time. Before that it's a temp value only

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Both answers are great, but I wont be able to achieve what I really wanted to do due to the limitation highlighted above.so my work around will be to direct users to the parent UNID and then provide a link to the actual document. Thanks.

Comment: PostSave event!

Comment: Implemented. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write your newly generated UniversalID into a sessionScope variable

```
sessionScope.newUnid = newDocId.getDocument().getUniversalID;
```

and use it in next XPage called after submit

```
var useTheNewUnid = sessionScope.newUnid;
```